# SQL Server query returning many cartesian product

Tags: sql, sql-server, cartesian-product

I have a SQL Server query which looks like this:

```
select 
    ISNULL(UPPER(w.role), '-') as 'Position Title',
    concat ('SGD ',m.expectedSalary) as 'Expected Salary',
    (cast(w.endYear as int) - cast(w.startYear as int)) as 'Experience',
    mq.Qualification as 'Education Level',
    ISNULL(ms.specialisation, '-') as 'Specialisation',
    mj.dateApplied as 'Date of Application'
from 
    WorkExpr w,
    Member m,
    MemberQlftn mq,
    MemberSpln ms,
    MemberJob mj
where 
    mj.jobNumber = (select jobNumber
                    from MemberJob
                    where email = 'alanang@gmail.com')
```

it is supposed to return me the details of people(such as the position tile, expected salary etc) who have applied for the same job as alan(which email is 'alanang@gmail.com'). However, when I run this query, I get over 6000 rows of data when I am only supposed to get back 4. can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You do realize that you have not joined any of those tables right?

Comment: @GurV how do i know if it is joined?

Comment: [Please checkout some basic SQL tutorials on JOINs first](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: Besides no joins at all... So we can see what's actually being queried from those tables, can you put the table alias prefixes on all those column names (mj.role, m.expectedSalary, mj.endYear, etc.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s this syntax was what my lecturer in school taught me so i did not really research much in other syntax but i will take your comment into consideration. thanks

Comment: TEll your lecturer to upgrade his teaching skills - seriously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now you need to replace your cross-join table list with INNER JOINS on their primary/foreign keys:

```
    from WorkExpr w,
    Member m,
    MemberQlftn mq,
    MemberSpln ms,
    MemberJob mj
```

replace with something like the following, but with the proper relationships between the tables:

```
    from WorkExpr w
    inner join Member m
        on w.memberid = m.memberid
    inner join MemberQlftn mq 
        on w.memberid = mq.memberid
    inner join MemberSpln ms
        on w.memberid = ms.memberid
    inner join MemberJob mj
        on w.memberid = mj.memberid
```