# return values of table 1 based on single column in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that I am using and need to make a query to return data from one table based on the value of a single column in the second table.

- tbl_user

  - ID
  - login
  - pass
  - active
  - mscID
- tbl_master

  - ID
  - name
  - training_date
  - MSCUnit
  - Active
- tbl_msc

  - mscID
  - mscName

my current SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT
   tbl_master.ID,
   tbl_master.name, 
   tbl_master.training_date, 
   tbl_master.MSCUnit,
   tbl_master.active, 
   tbl_user.mscID
 FROM
   tbl_master, 
   tbl_user
 WHERE
   tbl_master.active = 1 AND tbl_master.MSCUnit = tbl_user.mscID
```

The values stored in tbl_msc.mscID is a varchar(11) and it contains a string similar to A00 or A19.  This is also the Primary key in the table.

The values stored in tbl_user.mscID matches that of tbl_msc.mscID.  The values stored in tbl_master.UnitMSC also matches that of tbl_msc.mscID.

My goal is to return all records from tbl_master where the currently logged in user has the same mscID.  The problem I am having is the statement returns all records in tbl_master.

I have tried several different join statements and for some reason, I cannot get this to filter correctly.

I am missing something.  Any assistance in the SQL statement would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Will

Comment: Your problem stems from using a Cartesian product via multiple tables in your `FROM` clause. Use an `INNER JOIN` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query returning many cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172576/sql-server-query-returning-many-cartesian-product)

Comment: Also see [Performance of inner join compared to cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join)

Comment: And if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How do you know who the currently logged in user is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be writing this using `join`s.  I don't know how you know who the current user is, but the idea is to join the three tables together:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.name, m.training_date, m.MSCUnit, m.active, 
       u.mscID
FROM tbl_master m JOIN
     tbl_user u
     ON m.MSCUnit = u.mscID JOIN
     tbl_msc msc
     ON msc.mscID = u.msc_ID
WHERE m.active = 1 AND msc.mscName = ?;
```

Notice the use of proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax and table aliases.

Comment: that might be the step I'm missing.  I assumed since the user logs into the system the table would know the active user.  I guess I need to figure out a way to check for current user that is logged in.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select a.*, b.userid from 
table_master a, table_user b where 
a.mscunit in (select mscid from 
table_user where active=1)
```

This should point you in the right direction.